# select count postgres interval time

Tags: postgresql

I am using this to count data in that send in last 75 mints but i got always 0 , in the same time there is data sent in last 75 mints

```
select count(*) as result 
from data.data 
where last_send_date > (clock_timestamp() - interval '75 minutes')'';
```

Any tips where my mistake is (db engine postgres)?

Comment: The `''` at the end (before the `;` ) seem wrong.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT count(*) as results
FROM data
WHERE last_date BETWEEN (now() '- 45 minute'::interval)::timestamp
AND now();
```

Comment: @JJHardis can you please try this and comment? How does your current last_send_date format looks like?

Comment: its looks like " Sun Jan 13 12:59:39 GMT 2013  "